# FullCalendar and multiple event sources

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I have a couple of json feeds that I'd like to display on the calendar.

Looking at the docs there does seem some explanation, but no example of having more than 1 json feed.

I have the following:

```
var source = Array();
source[0] = '/feed1.php';
source[1] = '/feed2.php';
eventSources: [
  source[0],
  source[1]
]
```

This displays the events fine and I can seem them on my calendar

But how would I differentiate between them in terms of colors?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the extended form of event sources to give each source its own color.  In the code below, "color" is the event background color and "textColor" is the color of the event text.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  header: {
    left: 'prev,next',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'today'
  },

  eventSources: [
    {
      url: '/feed1.php',
      color: 'yellow',
      textColor: 'black'
    },
    {
      url: '/feed2.php',
      color: 'blue',
      textColor: 'white'
    }
  ]
});
```

Here's a JSFiddle that uses this method: http://jsfiddle.net/emcw5/4/.

Comment: Hi. When I use the above code, replacing `feedX.php` with the URLs to my JSON, no events are displayed. It doesn't even do a call to these scripts (looked in console). Any ideas?

Comment: If you click the 'Next' and then 'Prev' button, does that refresh the display? According to http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/, fullcalendar visits the URL whenever it needs new event data. I'm not sure why it's not calling those URLs on initial load. And, just to confirm, your URLs do return event data in JSON format, right?

Comment: FYI, I just noticed that I forgot to include the closing brackets on the last line. Just edited my answer to fix that.

Comment: Hi. I copied your code and replaced the feed urls. Mine do return JSON, but the events still don't appear...

Comment: Hmmm, do you see an actual calendar on the page? Any chance you could put your code into a JSFiddle?

Comment: I have added the code to jsbin and it works, just not in my application... strange

Comment: I have found the problem.... I was using version 1.4 of the fullcalendar lib. Updating has fixed my issues..

Comment: Ah, good to know! I was just scratching my head as to why it didn't work for you, when it works just fine for me. :) Glad you got it going.